# __add__ operator what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have to add two names together using the overloading operator **add**. My output should be both names added together for example: "john" + "frank" = 'JohnFrank'

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.aname = name


    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.person1 
        y = self.person2 
        print(x + y)
        return(Couple(x,y))

class Couple(Person):
    def __init__(self,person1,person2):
        self.person1 = person1
        self.person2 = person2
```

What am i doing wrong?

The error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    acouple = p1 + p2
  File "/Users/Desktop/NameP.py", line 7, in __add__
    x = self.person1
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'person1'
```

Comment: The only attribute your `Person` has is `aname`

Comment: `__add__` is a method of the class `Person`, so `self` will be bound to `p1` and `other` will be bound to `p2` in your call. So `self` will only have the member `aname`, but you want to construct the `Couple` out of the people `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: `return(Couple(self,other))`

Answer (score 1):

A `Person` object only has `aname` so you should pass the currect object `self` and the added object:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return Couple(self, other)
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is say i have       p1 = Person("Jon")    p2 = Person("Smith")   i want to add those two names together

Comment: In `Couple` try this: `def __str__(self): print self.person1.aname + self.person2.aname`

Comment: no it did not unfortunately however i figured it out on my own

Answer (score 0):

```
# This is what worked for me


class Person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.aname = name


    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.aname 
        y = self.aname 
        print(self.aname + " " + other.aname)
        return(Couple(x,y))


class Couple(Person):
    def __init__(self,person1,person2):
        self.person1 = person1
        self.person2 = person2
    enter code here
```